# Javascript "'x' is undefined" when defined a few lines before

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

The variable `layer` is defined a few lines before an object and is changed in that object, but does not allow me to give it a value, like so:

```
//using the phaser game engine
var layer;
var map;
Game.prototype = {
 create: function() {
  map = game.add.tilemap('testlevel');
  map.addTilesetImage('grassland');
  map.setCollisionByExclusion([1]);
  layer = map.createLayer('layer1');
  layer.resizeWorld(); //here is where the error occurs
 };
};
```

Comment: could you post the text of that error here

Comment: There's a difference between _declared_ and _`defined`_.   You have done the former, but it's likely that `map.createLayer()` is failing and returning an undefined value.

Comment: Could it be that `map.createLayer(...)` is returning null or undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know exactly without seeing more code, but this looks like map.createLayer('layer1'); is returning undefined so then you are calling a method (resizeWorld) on an undefined object.

I would check the return value of createLayer.